# Convert Jpanel to PNG image in java

Tags: java, jpanel

How to remove Background of Jpanel while converting image (png). I tried following line to remove the background of the panel but The converted image background become black.

```
g2.clearRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Saving a Java 2d graphics image as .png file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8202253/saving-a-java-2d-graphics-image-as-png-file)

Comment: `JPanel` does not support a image as a background by default. You have to implement that manually.

Comment: @ExtremeCoders that'd probably be an answer to this. Voting to reopen.

Answer (score 0):

draw a filled rectangle with the background color...

```
Color backGround = getBackGround();
g2.setColor(background);
g2.fillRect(0,0,getWidth(), getHeight() );
```