# How to create an Image from Graph?

Tags: java, image

Can somebody please give me some advice about how to save an image (PNG) from my created graph?

This is the java program:

```
public class GraphingData extends JPanel {
    int[] data = {
             110, 535, 0, 459, 380, 199, 212, 722, 332, 836, 149, 10, 656, 465, 100, 173, 277, 381, 685, 988, 89, 585, 381, 779, 378, 769, 265, 10 
    };
    final int PAD = 20;

    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)g;
        g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
                            RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        int w = getWidth();
        int h = getHeight();

        .......
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame f = new JFrame();
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.add(new GraphingData());
        f.setSize(1000,500);
        f.setLocation(200,200);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible dup to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8202253/saving-a-java-2d-graphics-image-as-png-file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To store a panel how it currently shown on screen (sizes etc.) to a file just do

```
BufferedImage bi = new BufferedImage(panel.getSize().width, panel.getSize().height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
panel.paint(bi.createGraphics());
ImageIO.write(bi, "PNG", new File("path/to/file.png"));
```

Besides that, do not use the Graphics that is given as parameter to `paintComponent` directly but call `g.create()` on it and if you are finished with that new instance call `dispose()` on it. You are expected to not change the Graphics object that is put in regarding colors, transformations and so on and with the `create()` and `dispose()` you make sure this is the case.

Comment: Fantastic, work fine! Thank you 
My question now is how to make a change and to save my Image without 
f.setvisible (true) 
if I do f.setvisible (false)  my saved  Image is only in black